# JCropped Get Cropped Image Height

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm using JCrop to get the dimensions of the image to be cropped. I have the code for getting the dimensions set like this:

```
            function updateCoordinates(c) {
                console.log(c)
                $('#image_x').val(c.x);
                $('#image_x2').val(c.x2);
                $('#image_y').val(c.y);
                $('#image_y2').val(c.y2);
                $('#image_w').val(c.w);
            }


            $('#jcrop_target').Jcrop({
                aspectRatio : 2 / 1,
                onSelect : updateCoordinates,
                onChange : updateCoordinates
            });
```

the variable 'c' has the values c.x, c.x2, c.y, c.y2 and c.w . I'm making a guess that c.w = width, c.x = x coordinates and c.y = y coordinates, but how do I get the height of the image? I am cry to pass the values into PHP Imagick cropping.

```
<?php    
$picture = new Imagick($this -> getOriginalUrl());
$picture->cropImage($width, $height, $x, $y);
```

I Feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

c.y2 - c.y gives the height of the cropped area.